# we have a # in the URL

Tags: seo

I am new in this SEO techniques. I created my website with this way:

- When www.mysite.com is typed it will redirect to a non-www version mysite.com
- One page HTML/PHP, no redirects or whatsoever
- Used a jquery plugin that scrolls to a specific `<div>` when a button/menu is clicked.
- My URL is constructed like this: `mysite.com/#about` and `mysite.com/#contact-us`

Is this SEO friendly? Because I noticed, whenever I typed the exact domain name on Google, it sees my website however when I do `mysite contact` or `mysite about` it doesn't see my website.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The # is not helpful, since the # is demarcated at the client side (in fact I believe it does not even get registered in your normal Apache access logs).

If you want to use the same structure though, try incorporating semantic mark-up to differentiate the two sections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what does this `semantic mark-up` mean?

Comment: It means using HTML tags which are not necessarily displayed but provide information on the structure of the page e.g <section>, <footer>, etc.